# Error while running di:compile command

Tags: di, setup-di-compile, compilation, command

Getting

> ReflectionException]   Class PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader does not exist

error while running

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command

[image]

Comment: can you share code where you use `PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader` class

Answer (score 1):

It happens when some class of other modules has been used in third modules and that module are not present in magento.

In your case `PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader` class is used in somewhere in other module expect **PayPal** module.
You need to remove the use of PayPal class from other modules or install module of PayPal which contain `PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader` Class in its file structure.

Comment: If my answer helps you then Please do up vote and accept the answer so it will helpful for other developers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` command to find the class `PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader` in your module

```
grep -rr1 "PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader"
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Answer (score 1):

[image: no output or error displayed after running command grep -rr1 "PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader" its showing only black screen]

no output or error displayed after running command grep -rr1 "PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader" its showing only black screen

Comment: you have to use `" "` i don't see any `" "`